# quiero traerme dos registro de mis campos ID y DISTRITO pero los distritos estan duplicados quiero traerme solo uno de ellos como lo hago?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

```
try{
                    require_once('conexion.php');
                    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT(TRIM(commerce_district)) AS commerce_district, commerce_id FROM `commerc` ORDER BY `commerc`.`commerce_district` ASC ";
                    // $sql2  = "SELECT commerce_district FROM `commerc`";

                    $resultado = $con->query($sql);
                    // $resultado2 = $con->query($sql2);

                }catch(Exception $e){
                    $error = $e->getMessage();
                }

<div class="estado pb-4">
                <div class="list-group" id="navbar-example">
                    <p class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active">Seleccione el estado</p>
                    <div class="scroll">
                        <?php while($distrito = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
                        <label for="checkbox" class="list d-flex">
                            <?php echo $distrito['commerce_district'] ?>
                            <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $distrito['commerce_id'] ?>" name="estado"
                             id="checkbox"/>
                        </label>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </div>
                    <!--fin scroll -->
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: pon el ejemplo de como te los está trayendo y como quieres que queden

Answer (score 0):

Trata de cambiar tu ciclo While por un ciclo For, pienso que asi aseguras que un mayor control sobre como se recorren los resultados que obtienes de la consulta SQL; quedaría algo asi:

```
<?php for($i=0;$distrito < $resultado->fetch_assoc();$i++) { ?>
                    <label for="checkbox" class="list d-flex">
                        <?php echo $distrito[$i]['commerce_district'] ?>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $distrito[$i]['commerce_id'] ?>" name="estado"
                         id="checkbox"/>
                    </label>
                    <?php } ?>
```

En caso de que no te sirva, trata de poner un condicional (If) dentro del ciclo que tienes y que se encargue de comparar el resultado actual con el anterior o siguiente, para que cuando sean iguales no lo vuelva a imprimir en pantalla y siga con el registro en la siguiente posicion del array.

Comment: No veo cómo de un bucle a otro se mejore la consulta

Comment: O por qué dices que un for es mejor?